# websphere liberty admincenter datasource

Tags: datasource, websphere-liberty

Recently, I switched to the websphere liberty 8.5.5.9. The adminCenter replaced the admin console. I used to configure many things in the admin console of lower Websphere version. but in the new admincenter, I couldn't find them any more, e.g. configure a datasource. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin Console is the UI for WebSphere Traditional whereas Admin Center is the UI for WebSphere Liberty.  Just like there are differences between the functionality of WebSphere Traditional and Liberty, same can be said for Admin Console and Admin Center.

Although Admin Center does not provide a 'wizard' type of experience that Admin Console does, you can use the Server Config tool to create a datasource and it can help guide you through the process by showing all the fields that can be set (including any defaults).  If you stay in the Design view for the configuration file (likely server.xml) of the server that you want to alter, you can select 'Add Child' and select 'Datasource.'  If will then populate all the fields with descriptions and defaults:
[Data Source in Design View of Server Config in Admin Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUwAX.png)

You can get similar assistance in the 'Source' view by activating content assist via ctrl+space.  This functionality is not unique to datasource, but is provided for all elements.

Answer (score 2):

In WebSphere Liberty you can configure your DataSource directly in the server.xml (similar to most server-level configurations in Liberty).

Here is an example from the Liberty documentation:

```
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/derbyEmbedded">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
    <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="C:/databases/SAMPLEDB" createDatabase="create"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="DerbyLib">
    <fileset dir="C:/db-derby-10.8.1.2-bin/lib"/>
</library>
```

To use a datasource, be sure to enable a JDBC feature in your server.xml, such as this:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

If you're not sure where to find your server.xml, by default it is in this location:

```
${wlp.install.dir}/servers/${your.server.name}/server.xml
```

For full doc on configuring data sources in Liberty, see:
 [Configuring relational database connectivity in Liberty](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html)

Comment: Yes. I saw they can be configured in the server.xml. But is the UI in the Admin Console are all gone as used in the lower Websphere versions? We change server.xml manually before. But sometimes the UI is handy.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to editing the server.xml as described by aguibert, you can create and edit data sources using the Liberty AdminCenter as described in this [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui_config.html).

Comment: Yes. But it's still adding entries to the server.xml. Nothing like the admin console  in websphere 8.5.5.1 and lower that you can click on the data source.

Comment: Granted it's adding entries to server.xml, but the WebSphere Application Server admin console is "just adding entries" to resources.xml.  Once you add the datasource amd jdbc drvier using the Liberty AdminCenter, you get UI panels that lead you through what you need to add, similar to the admin console.